How does the scoping in Mathematica work using with blocks?
I'm attempting to understand the following scoping issue:
In[1]:= ψ = Γ^2
           With[{Γ = 3}, {ψ, Evaluate[ψ]}]
           With[{Γ = 3}, Evaluate[ψ]]

Out[1]= Γ^2

Out[2]= {Γ^2, Γ^2}

Out[3]= 9


I think I am not understanding something basic about scoping. Can somebody point me to the proper reference pages to read?
Why does the second line not evaluate to {9, 9}, and why does Evaluate give different results in the second and third lines?
Thanks.

From the documentation:

Evaluate[expr]
causes expr to be evaluated even if it appears as the argument of a function whose attributes specify that it should be held unevaluated.

So, let's walk through your examples (with symbols that are easier for me to type):
Case 1
Given
p = g^2;

We start with
With[{g = 3}, {p, Evaluate[p]}]
(* The Evaluate appears as an argument to List which is itself inside of With. Any 
   Evaluate that is a direct argument of With would evaluate, but in this case there is no 
   such situation, so With just does its thing. Next, the With construct does *lexical* 
   replacements, so it looks for instances of literal "g" symbols, finds none and so 
   just evaluates the body to get... *)

{p, p} 
(* Now the evaluation engine continues the evaluation, finds the definition 
   for p and evaluates to... *)

{g^2, g^2}
(* If it finds no other definitions to apply, it'll just stop there. *)

Case 2
With[{g = 3}, Evaluate[p]]
(* In this case, Evaluate is an argument of With, which has the HoldAll attribute, 
   so Evaluate interrupts the normal evaluation order and forces itself to
   evaluate first... *)

With[{g = 3}, g^2]
(* Next comes the lexical replacement... *)

3^2
(* ...and finally... *)

9

